# Algorithm advice: Find count of number in sorted array

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

The problem:

> Let `A = A[1]<=A[2]....A[n]` be a sorted array of `n` numbers. Let `x` be a number. Design  an `O(log n)` time algorithm to find the number of times `x` appears in the array. What is the time complexity.

My answer:

Using a binary search find if `x = middle`. If `x` is middle then there is a chance `x` could appear in left and right side of middle. So create left array `L[]` and right array `R[]`. Using binary search find the the first time `x` appeared in `L[]`. Do the same thing for `R[]`, but to find the last time `x` appeared in `R[]`. Note the indexes. So the number of time `x` appeared = `Lastindex - FirstIndex + 1`. Time complexity 2log n + c = O(log n).  It's just a 'skeleton part' of algorithm since the  answer doesn't have to be elaborated. This is what I found, but is there a better solution?

Comment: Seems good (though a bit overcomplicated) to me. Note that depending on lanuage, creating the L[] and R[] array could be itself O(n) though (this can be solved by using the same array with referring to the first and last indices in each conceptual subarray)

Comment: @amit Thanks for pointing out, I meant to say sub-array's. And thanks for the quick replay.

Comment: This question would benefit from a better title and better formatting to make it easier to read.

Comment: There's a couple problem I see with your answer. 1. You talk about the case where the middle of the array is `x`, but you never go back to answer for if it isn't `x`. 2. There is no reason to create a separate left and right array, just do two binary searches on the original array and find the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Use a binary search to find the position of the first element >=x (or the end if there is no such element), and another binary search to find the position of the first element > x.  The difference between these positions is the number of elements == x.

```
int countXs(int[] array, int len, int x)
{
    int low, high, test;
    for (low=0, high=len; low<high;)
    {
        test = low+((high-low)>>1);
        if (array[test]>=x)
            high=test;
        else
            low=test+1;
    }
    int startPos = low;
    for (low=0, high=len; low<high;)
    {
        test = low+((high-low)>>1);
        if (array[test]>x)
            high=test;
        else
            low=test+1;
    }
    int endPos = low;
    return endPos - startPos;
}
```

Note that `low+((high-low)>>1)` is `floor((low+high)/2)`, but protected from overflows.  This is ALWAYS `>= low` and `< high`, so we can safely access `array[test]`.